# my Windows 8.1 need to set static IP when connect to wireless

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have only one Windows 8.1 PC at home. When it connects to wireless and set it to get IP automatically, it can get IP but no internet accessible, and if I set it as static IP(I specify the static IP to be as the same as the IP that it gets automatically), and it works fine now(can access the Internet normally).

What can do for this issue? Thanks.

Comment: It there any another network adapter on your PC (built-in, for example)? disable it (in Network connections window, for example).

Comment: I only have one wireless NIC and one wired NIC, and if I disable the wired NIC, the wireless connection can works fine when set it as automatically, now. Thanks! But why the wired NIC affected the wireless connection? It wasn't connected to anything.

Comment: When the wired NIC is enabled, and you connect with the wireless. What does "route print" command in CMD show you? Could it be old routes pointing to an old GW that no longer is active and reachable? also you could compare the DNS servers under "ipconfig /all".

Comment: *why the wired NIC affected the wireless connection?* Maybe wired NIC have IP address from the same subnet as wireless one. Maybe wired NIC have a default route. Maybe something else...

Comment: It is really strange, I have rebooted the machine, and now if it connects to wireless(automatically get IP) and the wired NIC is enabled, it works fine. I just forgot that reboot the machine always could be a solution. Thanks for your analysis, xstnc and Akina.